# EF 6.0.0.0 include linked table delete with reordering of data

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have this ef 6 delete method where I build `<List>` the related entities that will need to be deleted. Then I use `RemoveRange` to remove then. Once its deleted I will need to re-order the data and update the `SequenceOrder` field.

```
public ResultStatus DeleteMeetingPollingQuestion(int MeetingPollingQuestionId)
{
     using (var db = new NccnEcommerceEntities())
    {
        using (DbContextTransaction dbTran = db.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {

            ResultStatus result = new ResultStatus();

            try
            {
                var MeetingPollingQuestions = db.MeetingPollingQuestions.Find(MeetingPollingQuestionId);
                

                if (MeetingPollingQuestions != null)
                {
                    int? reorderinMeetingPollingId = MeetingPollingQuestions.MeetingPollingId;
                    var deleteMeetingPollingParts = db.MeetingPollingParts
                    .Where(task => task.MeetingPollingQuestionId == MeetingPollingQuestionId)
                    .ToList();

                    List<MeetingPollingPartsValue> deleteMeetingPollingPartsValues = new List<MeetingPollingPartsValue>();
                    foreach (var MeetingPollingParts in deleteMeetingPollingParts)
                    {
                        int MeetingPollingPartsId = MeetingPollingParts.MeetingPollingPartsId;
                        var MeetingPollingPartsValue = db.MeetingPollingPartsValues.Where(x => x.MeetingPollingPartsId == MeetingPollingPartsId).ToList();
                        deleteMeetingPollingPartsValues.AddRange(MeetingPollingPartsValue);
                    }

                    List<EFModel.MeetingPollingPartsValuesImage> deleteMeetingPollingPartsValuesImages = new List<EFModel.MeetingPollingPartsValuesImage>();
                    foreach (var MeetingPollingPartsValue in deleteMeetingPollingPartsValues)
                    {
                        int MeetingPollingPartsValueId = MeetingPollingPartsValue.MeetingPollingPartsValuesId;
                        var MeetingPollingPartsValuesImage = db.MeetingPollingPartsValuesImages.Where(x => x.MeetingPollingPartsValuesId == MeetingPollingPartsValueId).ToList();
                        deleteMeetingPollingPartsValuesImages.AddRange(MeetingPollingPartsValuesImage);
                    }


                    db.MeetingPollingPartsValuesImages.RemoveRange(deleteMeetingPollingPartsValuesImages);
                    db.MeetingPollingPartsValues.RemoveRange(deleteMeetingPollingPartsValues);
                    db.MeetingPollingParts.RemoveRange(deleteMeetingPollingParts);
                    db.MeetingPollingQuestions.Remove(MeetingPollingQuestions);

                    int? positionSequenceOrder = 1;


                    var reorderingmeetingpollingQuestions = db.MeetingPollingQuestions.Where(w=>w.MeetingPollingId == reorderinMeetingPollingId).OrderBy(x=>x.SequenceOrder).ToList();
                    
                    foreach (var updatereorderingQuestion in reorderingmeetingpollingQuestions.Where(w=>w.MeetingPollingQuestionId != MeetingPollingQuestionId))
                    {
                        updatereorderingQuestion.SequenceOrder = positionSequenceOrder;
                        db.Entry(updatereorderingQuestion).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                        positionSequenceOrder ++;
                    }


                    db.SaveChanges();
                    dbTran.Commit();
                }

                result.ResultCode = Convert.ToInt32(Enums.Result.Code.Success);
                result.Message = "Successfully uploaded.";
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                dbTran.Rollback();
                result.Message = "Error Save Meeting Polling Question" + e.Message;
                result.ResultCode = Convert.ToInt32(Enums.Result.Code.Error);

            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Specify the exact version of EF.

Comment: I updated the post with the version

Comment: As I know, EF4 does not have `Database.BeginTransaction` method.

Comment: sorry its version 6.0.0.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood the relations between your entities correctly, the code can be greatly simplified by making a single query using `Include`. This method load all related entities.
However, this single sql-query will be very complex, with multiple Joins.

After that, the `Remove` method will delete the entire hierarchy of objects in the cascade.

```
using (var db = new NccnEcommerceEntities())
{
    var meetingPollingQuestions = db.MeetingPollingQuestions
        .Include(x => x.MeetingPollingParts.Select(y => y.MeetingPollingPartsValues.Select(z => z.MeetingPollingPartsValuesImages)))
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.MeetingPollingQuestionId == MeetingPollingQuestionId);

    if (meetingPollingQuestions != null)
    {
        int? reorderinMeetingPollingId = meetingPollingQuestions.MeetingPollingId;

        db.MeetingPollingQuestions.Remove(meetingPollingQuestions);

        int? positionSequenceOrder = 1;

        var reorderingMeetingpollingQuestions = db.MeetingPollingQuestions.Where(w => w.MeetingPollingId == reorderinMeetingPollingId).OrderBy(x => x.SequenceOrder).ToList();

        foreach (var updateReorderingQuestion in reorderingMeetingpollingQuestions.Where(w => w.MeetingPollingQuestionId != MeetingPollingQuestionId))
        {
            updateReorderingQuestion.SequenceOrder = positionSequenceOrder;
            positionSequenceOrder++;
        }

        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

There is no need to manually set the entity `State` property. It will be marked as modified by itself.

---

It is very wasteful to download data from the database only to immediately remove it.
In pure SQL, your task can be solved with a single query directly in the database.
But Entity Framework is not able to generate such an efficient SQL.

You can look for extensions for EF that have Bulk Update and Remove operations. There are such extensions for EF Core.
Also, such amazing features have appeared in the newest EF Core 7 version. I advise you to take a closer look at it.

Comment: Is there anything within Ef that will handle the SequenceOrder?

Comment: @Jefferson `SequenceOrder` can be handled by DBMS side. like using computed column or using triggers.

Answer (score 2):

Quick remarks:

- `reorderinMeetingPollingId` is assigned but never used.
- Why don't you use `var` in assignments like `ResultStatus result = new ResultStatus();` and `List<MeetingPollingPartsValue> deleteMeetingPollingPartsValues = new List<MeetingPollingPartsValue>();` etc.?
- I understand that naming things is hard, but a class name like `MeetingPollingPartsValue` just baffles me, `MeetingPollingPartsValuesImage` (why are two parts of that name a plural?).
- `int MeetingPollingPartsId` and `var MeetingPollingPartsValue` etc. don't follow the capitalization guidelines; they should be camelCase. Ditto `MeetingPollingQuestionId`.
- Compound words should have each part capitalized. `updatereorderingQuestion` and `reorderingmeetingpollingQuestions` do not follow that guideline.
- Why is there a `Where` following `reorderingmeetingpollingQuestions` in the `foreach`? Why isn't that at the end of the assignment the line above?
- Do not pointlessly abbreviate, e.g. `dbTran`.
- `var MeetingPollingQuestions` doesn't follow the capitalization guidelines, plus it is a plural name despite it being a single item. This is confusing.
- Why is the property `ResultCode` an int? Why not make it an `enum`, so you won't need to convert your `enum` to an `int`?
- Why don't you simply cast your `enum` value to an `int` instead of doing `Convert.ToInt32(Enums.Result.Code.Success);`?
- I would advise against consolidating `enum`s in a folder/namespace named `Enums`. Moreover, why isn't your `enum` not called `ResultCode`?
- If I understand this correctly, you have a folder named "Result": `Enums.Result.Code.Success`? To me that feels wrong: folders are [namespaces and therefor should almost always be plural](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-namespaces).